# Calling an array into another array...?

Tags: java, arrays

Perhaps I'm not phrasing this correctly, but I have built a class that makes a dynamic array that doubles every time it reaches it's maximum from input. I am now trying to integrate that into another class that will make a list of strings using what I already built in the dynamic array class. Something like:

```
 public StringList() {
        DynamicArray2 StringList= new DynamicArray2();}
```

But I know that isn't right because then I can't refer to it for the rest of the class because it will be cut off. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking -- perhaps you can provide some more context, or an example showing what you're looking for? Be sure also to check the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Thanks!

Comment: use Arrays.copyOf to expand your array

Comment: I didn't understand either, explain more please.

Comment: I made a class that I called DynamicArray2 that creates a dynamic array. I am now trying to use this class in another class to create a list of strings. I want this new class to use the code I have in the DynamicArray2 class to create an array for this list... basically, use the DynamicArray2 class instead of rewriting all the code. I am trying to figure out how to create a new empty "StringList" object that uses the code from the DynamicArray2 class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume I understand what you are saying. You are declaring a variable inside of a class's constructor which, as you said, makes it out of scope with the rest of the class. Try moving the declaration outside of the constructor.

```
public class StringList {

    DynamicArray2 stringList;        

    public StringList() {
        stringList= new DynamicArray2();
    }

}
```

Or maybe you just want to have a publicly accessible DynamicArray2 object? Try:

```
public DynamicArray2 stringList = new DynamicArray2();
```

Comment: This seems to have worked, but now I am trying to add a string at an index, like "stringList[i]=a", which does not seem to be working. Any ideas?